# Unused path imported from django.urls

Tags: python, django

THIS IS THE ERROR
**Unused path imported from django.urlsPylintW0611:unused-import**
I don't know how to solve this.

iam using vscode
django version 4.2.4
Python 3.11.4

clientes/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    
]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well what is not clear about the error?

Comment: It's telling you that you imported `path` but then you never used it, which is a _suggestion_ that you might have made a mistake.  It is not an actual error.

Answer (score 2):

This is *not* an error, this is a warning by a *linter*. It means that you import `path`:

```
from django.urls import path
```

but in the rest of the code, you don't *use* path, hence the linter says you might have forgotten to use `path`, or you made a typo, or something else and therefore did not use `path`.

In order to silence the linter you thus either have to use `path` in one of the `urlpatterns` (you still have to define), or just omit the import.

Comment: Willem, Thank you.

I used path in mecajato/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('clientes/', include('clientes.url'))
]

Comment: @VascoMateus: but you import it in a file where you don't use it, of course in other files you can use it, but even if that is the case the `import` is either unnecessary in *that* file, or you forgot to use it in *that* file.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I can understand now, and it is working.